Nginx SSL_get_error: 6 when client tries to access the service from .NET app
We have a web service that is positioned like Nginx => Docker(Nginx => django). We have been running our services for about 4 years now and this week one of our new client, when they try to send a request they get connection closed message. As far as I know they are trying to connect to our services from a .NET app, I am not aware of their .NET version or whatsoever. Our outermost nginx app is handling SSL traffic and here is the log when they try to connect:
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_get_error: 2
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL handshake handler: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 ssl new session: 6227BEFF:32:180
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=AES(128) Mac=SHA256"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 reusable connection: 1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http wait request handler
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 malloc: 000055CAE04C3FD0:1024
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_read: -1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_get_error: 2
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE04C3FD0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http wait request handler
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 malloc: 000055CAE04C3FD0:1024
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_read: 222
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_read: -1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_get_error: 2
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 reusable connection: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 posix_memalign: 000055CAE06CB900:4096 @16
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http process request line
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http request line: "POST /extapi/get_token/ HTTP/1.1"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http uri: "/extapi/get_token/"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http args: ""
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http exten: ""
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 posix_memalign: 000055CAE0729140:4096 @16
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http process request header line
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http header: "Host: mydomain.tld"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http header: "Accept: application/json"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http header: "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http header: "Content-Length: 56"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http header done
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 event timer del: 29: 33181363237
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 generic phase: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 rewrite phase: 1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 test location: "/"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 using configuration "/"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http cl:56 max:0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 rewrite phase: 3
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 post rewrite phase: 4
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 generic phase: 5
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 generic phase: 6
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 generic phase: 7
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 access phase: 8
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 access phase: 9
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 access phase: 10
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 post access phase: 11
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 generic phase: 12
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 generic phase: 13
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http client request body preread 56
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http request body content length filter
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http body new buf t:1 f:0 000055CAE04C4076, pos 000055CAE04C4076, size: 56 file: 0, size: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 epoll add event: fd:29 op:3 ev:80002005
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: "Host"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: "mydomain.tld"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: "X-Real-IP"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script var: "x.x.x.x"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-For"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script var: "x.x.x.x"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Proto"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: "https"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: "Connection"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: "close"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: "Content-Length"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script var: "56"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http script copy: ""
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Accept: application/json"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header:
"POST /extapi/get_token/ HTTP/1.0
Host: mydomain.tld
X-Real-IP: x.x.x.x
X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Connection: close
Content-Length: 56
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http cleanup add: 000055CAE0729C28
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 get rr peer, try: 1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 stream socket 30
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 epoll add connection: fd:30 ev:80002005
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 connect to 127.0.0.1:9022, fd:30 #80
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream connect: -2
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 posix_memalign: 000055CAE0787260:128 @16
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 event timer add: 30: 36000000000:69181303461
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http finalize request: -4, "/extapi/get_token/?" a:1, c:2
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http request count:2 blk:0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http run request: "/extapi/get_token/?"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/extapi/get_token/"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream request: "/extapi/get_token/?"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream send request handler
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream send request
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream send request body
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 chain writer buf fl:0 s:271
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 chain writer buf fl:1 s:56
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 chain writer in: 000055CAE0729C88
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 writev: 327 of 327
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 event timer del: 30: 69181303461
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 event timer add: 30: 36000000000:69181303465
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream request: "/extapi/get_token/?"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream process header
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 malloc: 000055CAE078A590:4096
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 recv: fd:30 380 of 4096
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy status 200 "200 OK"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Server: nginx"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2024 06:10:54 GMT"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Content-Type: application/json"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Content-Length: 52"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Vary: Accept-Encoding"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Allow: POST, OPTIONS"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Vary: Origin, Cookie"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 posix_memalign: 000055CAE0723C70:4096 @16
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "X-Frame-Options: DENY"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header: "Referrer-Policy: same-origin"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy header done
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 xslt filter header
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2024 06:10:54 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 52
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Vary: Origin, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: same-origin

2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055CAE0723D98, pos 000055CAE0723D98, size: 349 file: 0, size: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:349
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http cacheable: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http proxy filter init s:200 h:0 c:0 l:52
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream process upstream
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 pipe read upstream: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 pipe preread: 52
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000055CAE078A590, pos 000055CAE078A6D8, size: 52 file: 0, size: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 pipe length: 52
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 input buf #0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 pipe write downstream: 1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 pipe write downstream flush in
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http output filter "/extapi/get_token/?"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http copy filter: "/extapi/get_token/?"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 image filter
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 xslt filter body
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http postpone filter "/extapi/get_token/?" 000055CAE0729C98
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055CAE0723D98, pos 000055CAE0723D98, size: 349 file: 0, size: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055CAE078A590, pos 000055CAE078A6D8, size: 52 file: 0, size: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:401
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http copy filter: 0 "/extapi/get_token/?"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 pipe write downstream done
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 event timer: 30, old: 69181303465, new: 69181303545
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream exit: 0000000000000000
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 finalize http upstream request: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 finalize http proxy request
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free rr peer 1 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 close http upstream connection: 30
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE0787260, unused: 48
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 event timer del: 30: 69181303465
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 reusable connection: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http upstream temp fd: -1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http output filter "/extapi/get_token/?"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http copy filter: "/extapi/get_token/?"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 image filter
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 xslt filter body
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http postpone filter "/extapi/get_token/?" 00007FFE7ADDF5B0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055CAE0723D98, pos 000055CAE0723D98, size: 349 file: 0, size: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055CAE078A590, pos 000055CAE078A6D8, size: 52 file: 0, size: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000000000000000, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:401
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http write filter limit 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 posix_memalign: 000055CAE04F6580:512 @16
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 malloc: 000055CAE0781500:16384
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL buf copy: 349
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL buf copy: 52
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL to write: 401
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_write: 401
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http write filter 0000000000000000
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http copy filter: 0 "/extapi/get_token/?"
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http finalize request: 0, "/extapi/get_token/?" a:1, c:1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 set http keepalive handler
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http close request
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http log handler
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 geoip2 http log handler
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE078A590
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE06CB900, unused: 6
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE0729140, unused: 16
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE0723C70, unused: 2723
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE04C3FD0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 hc free: 0000000000000000
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE0781500
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 reusable connection: 1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 event timer add: 29: 14400000:33195703545
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 http keepalive handler
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 malloc: 000055CAE04C3FD0:1024
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_read: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_get_error: 6
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 peer shutdown SSL cleanly
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [info] 3381249#3381249: *79 client x.x.x.x closed keepalive connection
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 close http connection: 29
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 SSL_shutdown: 1
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 event timer del: 29: 33195703545
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 reusable connection: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE04C3FD0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 0000000000000000
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE04CDC60, unused: 0
2024/09/17 09:10:54 [debug] 3381249#3381249: *79 free: 000055CAE04F6580, unused: 384

Our current configuration of nginx is as follows:
server {
        server_name mydomain.tld;

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

#       ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
#       ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
#       ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam;

        ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:sect571r1:secp521r1:secp384r1;

        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA;
#       ssl_ciphers TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
#       ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
#       ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9022;
                proxy_set_header        Host mydomain.tld;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_connect_timeout   36000000;
                proxy_send_timeout                      36000000;
                proxy_read_timeout                      36000000;
                send_timeout                                            36000000;
        }
}

Result of nginx -V
user@server:/var/log$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/nginx-dSlJVq/nginx-1.18.0=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-compat --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-dSlJVq/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_sub_module

They have been doing nothing but waiting for us to fix the issue but for me the issue feels like on the client side, I mean we have been running this service for 4 years now and never heard of an issue like this before, we all can use the service on chrome/postman and etc, the client even can use our service when they are testing. They told us they had similar issue like this and it was on server side and they managed to fix it. How do I even fix this issue?

I don't see any problems in the outout from nginx. Normal TLS handshake, HTTP request, HTTP response, proper TLS shutdown.

I am not very familiar with nginx logs but from what I understand, "SSL_get_error: 6" does not necessarily mean an error I think. The client seems to be receiving 200 status code and response looks normal. I think the issue might be somewhere else on their side.
